# Azure bicep template tag OSDisk throws error on 'deleteOption' setting

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-bicep

I am trying to create an Azure VM using bicep file:

```
resource linuxVm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2020-06-01' = {
  name: linuxVm.vmName
  location: location
   
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: linuxVm.vmSize
    }
    storageProfile: {
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        deleteOption: 'Delete' //This line throws error
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: linuxVm.osDiskType
        }
      }
```

When i want to delete the VM i want the OS disk also to be deleted so set this option:
**deleteOption: 'Delete'** in storageprofile section.

But am getting this error during deployment of bicep:

```
"BadRequest","message": "Could not find member 'deleteOption' on object of type 'OSDisk'. Path 'properties.storageProfile.osDisk.deleteOption', line 1, position 231."target": "vm.properties.storageProfile.osDisk.deleteOption
```

What is the mistake here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially, When I tried with version **`[2020-06-01]`** **`linuxVm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2020-06-01'`** in my environment. I got same error.

[image]

According to [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI), I tried with the resource virtual machine having document version [**`2021-11-01`**]** i.e. `vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-11-01'`**
in bicep format.

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
Using above Microsoft bicep code with version. I am able to successfully deploy the virtual machine with **deleteOption: 'Delete'**.

**Console:**
[image]

I also checked in portal with **`json view`**:

[image]

In my environment, I deleted the virtual machine manually to check the **`os disk`** to delete and it successfully deleted both **`Virtual machine and os disk`** perfectly.

[image]

**Result:**
[image]